# Valores repetidos ao fazer um INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

Esse código abaixo está trazendo valores repetidos na tela.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

```
$id_credenciado = $_SESSION['id_credenciado'];    

//$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tb_protocolo INNER JOIN tb_certidao ON tb_protocolo.id_credenciado = tb_certidao.id_credenciado WHERE tb_protocolo.id_credenciado = $id_credenciado AND tb_certidao.id_credenciado = $id_credenciado");

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tb_protocolo INNER JOIN tb_certidao WHERE tb_protocolo.id_credenciado = $id_credenciado AND tb_certidao.id_credenciado = $id_credenciado");
```

Comment: Esse código está trazendo valores repetidos na tela....Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Como estão suas estruturas de tabelas?

Comment: Se você usar `*` na query vai trazer tudo das duas tabelas, e é absolutamente ok trazer dados duplicados, se não for uma relação `1:1`. Veja que algum campo deve ser diferente, não vai ser tudo 100% igual. `DISTINCT` não vai resolver o problema com `*` porque qualquer campo diferente configura uma linha diferente

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade não está trazendo valores repetidos.

O que acontece é que o distinct compara todas as colunas.

Basta uma coluna no registro estar diferente que ele já vai separar em dois registros.

Para solucionar isso você precisa especificar somente as colunas da busca que você precisa, ao invés de trazer todas usando o asterisco (*).

Answer (score 0):

Teste fazer assim:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, 
"SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM tb_protocolo p INNER JOIN tb_certidao c ON c.id_credenciado = p.id_credenciado WHERE c.id_credenciado = $id_credenciado");
```

Estamos juntando a tabela de certidão na consulta ligando ao código principal da primeira tabela.